# move_base without base_local_planner

Tags: navigation, move-base, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an alternative navigation package that generates cmd_vel messages given the plans published on /move_base/NavfnROS/plan. I already redirected topics and everything runs well... but there is a lot of wasted overhead processing in move_base. What is the best method for stripping move base of its local planner?

A couple more specifics:

1. We are using the default global planner ("navfn/NavfnROS")
2. We want to use both the global and local costmaps to produce a plan

Should I be:
A) stripping the base_local_planner from the source code?
B) write a separate planning node from scratch
C) maybe there is a parameter I can set?
D) something else?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209608/move_base-without-base_local_planner/) by [ebeowulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2856/ebeowulf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2015-05-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the easiest solution would be to still use move base, but only use the Service Call to create the plans

```
~make_plan
```

As described here (1.1.5):
http://wiki.ros.org/move_base

Then move_base will still generate the plan based on the local and global costmap, but not execute the plan, and your node can use it to navigate.
You could additionally create a "fake local planner" code, which essentially does nothing to reduce some of the memory of move_base, but I am not sure how much effect that would have, since it should never be executed anyway.

---

Originally posted by [daenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/3203/daenny/) with karma: 376 on 2015-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ebeowulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2856/ebeowulf/) on 2015-05-22**:
I didn't think about the Service Call - although the node mentioned by David may work as well (haven't tried it yet), the service call solves one of my other problems where move base fails in the middle of executing a plan